# Issue parsing JSON array without key

Tags: android, json, google-places-api, arrays

I am trying to use Google Places API and I am basically trying to parse the Json without the key in a specific position in the json.

I am able to parse all the data and getting the values as required. 
Although, I am having issues with one of the parts in that json.

**Here's the json sample :**

```
{
   "html_attributions":[],
   "results":[
      {
         "geometry":{
            "location":{
               "lat":somelat,
               "lng":somelng
            }
         },
         "icon":"someicon",
         "id":"someid",
         "name":"somename",
         "reference":"some_image_reference",
         "types":[
            "gas_station",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity":"Some Address"
      }
   ],
   "status":"OK"
}
```

Now, here's the **code snippet** to get the values from where I am having trouble:

```
JSONObject mainJSONObject = new JSONObject(mAppUtils.loadJSON(gasURL));
            JSONArray mainJSONArray = mainJSONObject.getJSONArray("results");

            for(int i = 0 ; i<mainJSONArray.length();i++){

                JSONObject obj = mainJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            if(obj!=null){

                            String value = obj.getString("types");

                            Log.d("ARRAY VALUE : ", value);
                            }


            }
```

Here, the code is working perfectly and I am able to get the data.

The main issue is the result format. Here's a sample :

```
06-23 22:03:51.762: D/ARRAY VALUE :(8074): ["car_repair","gas_station","establishment"]
06-23 22:03:51.782: D/ARRAY VALUE :(8074): ["convenience_store","food","store","car_repair","gas_station","establishment"]
06-23 22:03:51.782: D/ARRAY VALUE :(8074): ["gas_station","establishment"]
```

As you can see, the result I am getting in this format : **["car_repair","gas_station","establishment"]**

Is there a better way to parse the above json or is there any way I can replace the characters and braces from 
**["car_repair","gas_station","establishment"]**

to just like :

**car_repair,gas_station,establishment** so that I can use it in my textview of any other view without showing those braces and other characters.

**EDIT:**

```
    JSONObject mainJSONObject = new JSONObject(mAppUtils.loadJSON(gasURL));
            JSONArray mainJSONArray = mainJSONObject.getJSONArray("results");

                    for(int j=0;j<mainJSONArray.length();j++)
                   {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = mainJSONArray.getJSONObject(j);

                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("types");

                    for(int ju=0;ju<jsonArray.length();ju++)
                     {
                          value =  jsonArray.getString(ju); 
                         Log.d("PLACE TYPES ARRAY VALUE : ", value);
                     }
```

After this, here's the result I got :

```
06-23 22:53:44.928: D/PLACE TYPES ARRAY VALUE :(16322): car_repair
06-23 22:53:44.928: D/PLACE TYPES ARRAY VALUE :(16322): gas_station
06-23 22:53:44.928: D/PLACE TYPES ARRAY VALUE :(16322): establishment
06-23 22:53:44.928: D/PLACE TYPES ARRAY VALUE :(16322): convenience_store
06-23 22:53:44.938: D/PLACE TYPES ARRAY VALUE :(16322): food
06-23 22:53:44.938: D/PLACE TYPES ARRAY VALUE :(16322): store
06-23 22:53:44.938: D/PLACE TYPES ARRAY VALUE :(16322): car_repair
06-23 22:53:44.938: D/PLACE TYPES ARRAY VALUE :(16322): gas_station
06-23 22:53:44.938: D/PLACE TYPES ARRAY VALUE :(16322): establishment
06-23 22:53:44.938: D/PLACE TYPES ARRAY VALUE :(16322): gas_station
06-23 22:53:44.938: D/PLACE TYPES ARRAY VALUE :(16322): establishment
```

But the problem is, how do I separate the values from their respected json array.

Any help will be really appreciated.. Thanks .. :)

Comment: `"types":[` is a JSONArray

Comment: I understand that but I tried to use JSONArray as well and I did get the results but for some reason, then I do 

JSONArray typesJsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("types");
        String value = typesJsonArray.getString(i);

It gives me the error.

Comment: you have types as an an array and you have to loop through that array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the array and get the value based on the index

```
 for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.length().i++)
 {
        String value = (String) jsonarray.get(i); // Note the cast
 }
```

You can also use `getString(i)` or `getInt(i)`

Instead of this

```
 String value = obj.getString("types");
```

Have

```
 JSONArray jsonarray = obj.getJSONArray("types");

 for(int j=0;j<jsonarray.length();j++)
 {
        String value =  jsonarray.getString(j); 
 }
```

Edit 2:

Have

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new  ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

Then in for loop

```
 HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>():
 map.put("key",value);
 list.add(map)
```

TO get

```
HashMap<String,String> map =  (HashMap<String,String> ) list.get(0);// 0 is the index of item
String value =(String)map.get("key");
```

Comment: Cant use JSONArray jsonarray =  obj.getJSONArray("types") since "types" is a part of the results array. The thing is, I am able to get the values with my code too but again, its all wrapped in the braces.

Comment: @mike20132013 types is a jsonarray so loop through it and get the values see the edited part and it should work fine. Log the value of string and check. WIthout braces

Comment: @mike20132013 you have a json object node` after results array and where does that close/end?? ends here    `"vicinity":"Some Address"
      }`

Comment: The json provided is just a JSON Sample. I edited my Question and I am getting the values. But still not clear with the concept of parsing the json without it's key.

Comment: @mike20132013 its simple `[` represents json array node and `{` represetns json object node. You get the value with key if you have a key pair. What you have is a types array with just values. loop through the array and get the value. What is that you still don't understand??

Comment: @mike20132013 just think that it is just an array of String

Comment: @mike20132013 you can use a arraylist of hashmap and add items. Once you get the values its upto you to handle the data how you want

Comment: Thanks for the info. I got the concept. Now, after getting the values as in the code, how will I separate the values from other json blocks ? Because, it's like you are getting a set of results.

Comment: @mike20132013 and check edit2 if you still don't get it then i can do no more