# Retrieve JSON data returned from GOOGLE FINANCE API URL in android

Tags: json, android-json, stockquotes, google-finance, google-finance-api

I am using the following URL to get quotes information of any company.
http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=bom:ranbaxy

(here ranbaxy is the company).

what website or url returns is given below.

```
[ {
"id": "672832" ,
"t" : "500359" ,
"e" : "BOM" ,
"l" : "859.90" ,
"l_fix" : "859.90" ,
"l_cur" : "Rs.859.90" ,
"s": "0" ,
"ltt":"3:50PM GMT+5:30" ,
"lt" : "Apr 1, 3:50PM GMT+5:30" ,
"lt_dts" : "2015-04-01T15:50:23Z" ,
"c" : "" ,
"c_fix" : "" ,
"cp" : "" ,
"cp_fix" : "" ,
"ccol" : "" ,
"pcls_fix" : "859.9" 
} ]
```

in the following returned json values objectname or array name is not given . i am unable to retrieve the data from this url.

i just want to show each data in TextView. i have extended AsyncTask in the class where i am getting the values.

need the solution for it. thanks in Advance.

Comment: From their web site: "The Google Finance APIs are no longer available."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a json array. use

```
JSONArray jsar=new JSONArray(result);
```

Then use for loop to parse.Also, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377479/issue-parsing-json-array-without-key)

Hope this helps